# Interference of \addtokomafont and subcaption

Tags: captions, koma-script, subcaption

Dear stackexchange users,

the document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\textbf}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

does not compile with

```
pdflatex 2018.6.18
scartcl 3.25
subcaption 1.1-162
caption 3.3-147
```

I guess the caption definitions don't get along well. Do you guys have any idea how to fix this issue?

The error message looks like the following

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.8     \caption{test}

? 
! Extra \endcsname.
<argument> ...t \csname fnum@\@captype \endcsname 
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
l.8     \caption{test}

? 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.8     \caption{test}

? 
! Extra \endcsname.
<argument> ...t \csname fnum@\@captype \endcsname 
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
l.8     \caption{test}
```

Regards

Comment: Note in general: Users without expert knowledge should use only the font commands listed in the description of `\addtokomafont` and `\setkomafont`. The manual also says: “*The use of other commands […] is not supported. Strange behaviour is possible in these cases and does not represent a bug.*”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}% <- changed
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tanks, that helped.